# ngx translate Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, ngx-translate

When I change the language in settings.ts (page) and check currentLanguage in the same page, it changes the language correctly and show it.

But when I do the same thing in app.component.ts, CurrentLanguage does not change even if i change it 10 times.

Here is the code.  Button for language change is in settings.html

**settings.ts**

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

constructor(private translate: TranslateService){
   //code...
}
changeLang(lang){
  this.translate.use("en");
  console.log("Switched to ", this.translate.currentLang);
  this.translate.use("ru");
  console.log("Switched to ", this.translate.currentLang);
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';


constructor(private translate: TranslateService){
   //code...
}

this.translate.use("ru");
  console.log("it is   ", this.translate.currentLang);
this.translate.use("en");
  console.log("it is   ", this.translate.currentLang);
this.translate.use("ru");
  console.log("it is   ", this.translate.currentLang);
```

*Output for settings.ts*

```
Switched to  en 
Switched to  ru
```

Output for app.component.ts

```
it is    to ru
it is    to ru
it is    to ru
```

Comment: Do you only have a single AppModule or do you have multiple?

Comment: @Daniel Single.